# extend oval 15 times

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm a beginner java programmer and I'm taking cmpe courses. I'm drawing oval and I want it to move 15 times x coordinate by 5

```
import acm.graphics.;
import acm.program.*;

public class proje extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run(){
        int x=1;
        int y=1;

        GOval f = new GOval(x,y,5,5);
        add(f);
        for (int i = 1; i <strong text=15; i++)
            x= x+5;
    }
}
```

here is my code applet shows initial oval but it does not draw 15 times again any help will be useful for me thank you

Comment: All this code does is to add 5 to `x` 15 times. You presumably need the `GOval f` and `add(f)` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class proje extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run(){

        for (int x = 1; i <= 76; x+=5){
            GOval f = new GOval(x,1,5,5);
            add(f);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is based on the assumption that your "add"-Method somehow stores the oval in an array and then displays it. If this is not the case, please precise your question.

It basically creates 16 different oval-objects and then adds them. You will have to somehow "redraw" your screen for every single oval-object. Maybe add more code to your question.